# Duplicate entires into database while using ajax to insert

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to user ajax to insert into the database for my laravel project but each time i insert i see duplicates of every item with a unique id.
Inserting normally with the form itself, this behavior doesn't repeat.

My ajax code s below.

```
    `$('#saveCat').on('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });


    var url = '/admin/storecat';
    var type = "post";

    var data = {spec: $('#cat').val() };

    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            $('#catform').trigger('reset');

            //show success alert msg
            $('#alert-suc').html(data);
            $('#ac-alert').show('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#ac-alert').hide('slow');
                }, 3000);
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

My controller action here

```
public function storeCat(Request $request) {

$Category = new Category;

$Category->name = $request->spec;
$Category->save();

return response()->json('New service category ' . $request->spec . ' has been added.');
```

}

Comment: did you check on chrome console if your JS is doing 2 requests?

Comment: also check if it works correctly without `$('#catform').trigger('reset');`. this could be the cause.

Comment: Ok let me check that now.

Comment: How do i check if js is doing two requests please?

Comment: Try check the network tab.

Comment: I just checked on the console and the success message 
New service category "value" has been added.  
appears twice.
What do i do to fix this?

Comment: Is the `saveCat` button a form submit button?

Comment: yes, it is a button.

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

e.stopImmediatePropagation();

`stopImmediatePropagation` will prevent any parent handlers and also any other handlers from executing.